# Do ground loops matter with the Pi Pico?

Tags: ground, ground-loop, raspberry-pi-pico

The [Pi Pico's pinout](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/Pico-R3-A4-Pinout.pdf) contains multiple ground pins:
[image]

My understanding is that this will create ground loops where current can flow.

Is this a problem? Should I only use one of the ground pins?

Comment: your understanding would seem incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *My understanding is that this will create ground loops where current
> can flow.*

Ground loops can be problematic when multiple "earths" are involved. "Ground" may be referred to as "earth" in some areas of the world but, ground, as a node name (or alias of 0 volts) is not very often problematic when multiple common connections are made e.g. when we use ground planes to reduce EMI susceptibility.

Multiple earths (on the other hand) can inadvertently redirect earth fault currents from one equipment via sensitive inputs of other equipment instead of using the normal path for these currents. This can be a big problem AND can cause damage.

On the other hand, 0 volt return wires (aka ground) may carry "spikey" currents that can upset sensitive areas of the same circuit and, in those situations, star-point grounds are recommended.

> *Should I only use one of the ground pins?*

Use them all but pay particular attention to ground pins that are used to convey analogue return signals. These may require a form of star-pointing to achieve optimum noise performance.